# How to tell whether job failed or was aborted

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I've got a Jenkins job with a `try..catch` structure:

```
try
{
  [do work here]
}
catch(err)
{
}
```

Is there any way, from inside the `catch` block, that I can tell whether the build failed or was aborted by the user?

I've tried looking at `err.getMessage()`, `err.getCause()`, `err.toString()`, and `currentBuild.result`, but none of them consistently tell me whether it failed or was aborted.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there's no consistent way to tell if a build was failed or aborted. When a user interrupts a build a java.lang.InterruptedException is thrown, so you could start with that. Be careful with other code which could throw an InterruptedException, like the input() step when aborted.

So you could do something like:

```
try
{
    [do work here]
}
catch(err)
{
    if (err instanceof InterruptedException) {
        [handle error]
    } else {
        [handle error]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm finding that there's some problematic code in the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin that prevents this from working when interrupting a Gradle execution.  It's trapping any exception and re-throwing Run.RunnerAbortedException, which makes it impossible to distinguish InterruptedException from any other.  https://github.com/joventuraz/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/steps/ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java#L198

Answer (score 1):

The aborted status will be setted at `build.status` or `currentBuild.result`,
according to the issue from Jenkins official Jira issue (
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43339 ):

> Regrettably, not much we can do here - the ABORTED status, in some cases, doesn't get set until the Pipeline finishes executing, so we can't tell from Declarative that we should be treating the build as ABORTED.